# Формула в строке

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста решение:
Есть строковая переменная в которой формула вида: 11*76
Задача посчитать результат.
Какое решение можно применить? Кроме eval.

Comment: сделайте свой компилятор арифметических выражений - это не сложно. Самое сложное парсер числа  произвольного формата

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: explode (какой вопрос, такой ответ)

Comment: Можете воспользоваться этим компонентом от symfony https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html

Answer (score 0):

Например, с помощью регулярных выражений.

```
$str = "11*76";
preg_match("/^(?<number1>\d+)(?<operator>\*|\/|\+|\-)(?<number2>\d+)$/", $str, $matches);
$number1 = $matches['number1'] ?? null;
$number2 = $matches['number2'] ?? null;
$operator = $matches['operator'] ?? null;

if ($number1 && $number2 && $operator) {
    switch ($operator) {
        case "*":
            $result = $number1 * $number2;
        break;
        case "/":
            $result = $number1 / $number2;
            break;
        case "+":
            $result = $number1 + $number2;
            break;
        case "-":
            $result = $number1 - $number2;
            break;
    }
    echo "{$number1} {$operator} {$number2} = {$result}";
}
```